# Boost Beast. Three sessions per request?

Tags: boost-beast

I've tried to run Boost-Beast example http_server_async.cpp. It worked fine (used one thread, windows with mingw64, gcc 10.2), but after some time I got three messages:

```
read: The socket was closed due to a timeout
read: The socket was closed due to a timeout
read: The socket was closed due to a timeout
```

I guess it happens due to timeout, which is set to 30 seconds in session::do_read method and if we modify condition in method session::on_read to:

```
if(ec == http::error::end_of_stream || ec == beast::error::timeout) return do_close();
```

It should do the trick. But what worries me is that we have 3 messages even though only one request was sent (from Chrome). I checked - yes, three session were created on that request.

So I have couple of questions:

1. Can we register some graceful close on timeout instead of going to on_read callback?
2. Why were 3 session created on a single request?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Chrome creates 3 connections. Firefox creates 2 connections and closes one immediately. If I run it with curl or my own client only one connection is accepted on the server side.